# How to render fabric.Image with scale?

Tags: fabricjs

Fabric version is 2.x
I tried to create my class for display images. But when i resize object of my class (change width and height, not scale), image always have default size. Can you help me with this?

```js
    MyImage = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {

    image: null, //will be instance of Fabric.Image

    _render(ctx) {
        if (this.image) {

            this.image.set({
                scaleX: this.width / this.image.width,
                scaleY: this.height / this.image.height
            });

            this.image._render(ctx);
        }
    },
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solve it. You need to use render instead of _render.

```js
    _render(ctx) {
        if (this.image) {
            ctx.save();

            ctx.translate(-this.width / 2, -this.height / 2);

            this.image.set({
                scaleX: this.width / this.image.width,
                scaleY: this.height / this.image.height
            });
            this.image.render(ctx);
            ctx.restore();
        }
    },
```